# Can't pass a property (as props) of fetched data object from child component to another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-props

I want to pass the **id property** of the fetched data object from **a child component** (nested in **Home.js**) to **another page** (**RecipeDetails.js**) as props but `console.log(props.id)` is always empty. I'm not good with explaining in words so I drew a diagram to show my data flow (hopefully it makes sense to everyone): https://www.dropbox.com/s/5xo3u9lvzat70rh/explaination.png?dl=0

I guess it has something to do with the `<Link></Link>` tags wrapped around the items that prevent the ids from being passed to the **RecipeDetails.js** but I'm not sure.

This is my app structure:
`App.js` 
----`Home.js` 
       ----`StaffPicks.js` 
            ----`<Card/>` 
                  ----`<Link id={item.id} to="/RecipeDetails">`
                               `<Item/>`
                         `<Link/>` 
          
----`RecipeDetails.js`

`App.js` Component:

```js
function App(){

const [value, setValue] = useState("");
const [id, setId] = useState("");

//for testing purposes
const testing = "testing";
console.log({ id: id, testing: testing });

useEffect(() => {}, [id]);
useEffect(() => {}, [value]);

  return(
    <Switch>
      <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          component={() => (<Home/>)}
       />
       <Route
          path="/RecipeDetails"
          exact
          component={() => <RecipeDetails id={id}/>}
       />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

`Card.js` Component:

```js
const MiniDishCard = (props) => {
  const [cardId, setCardId] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cardId !== "") {
      props.setId(cardId);
    }
  }, [cardId]);

  return (
    <Gallery>
      {props.data.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <Link
            className="link"
            to={`/RecipeDetails`}
            target="_blank"
            key={index}
            id={item.id}
            onClick={(e) => {
              setCardId(e.currentTarget.id);
            }}
          >
            <MiniCard>
              <ImageWrapper>
                <img src={item.image} alt="Recipe Picture" />
              </ImageWrapper>
              <TextWrapper>
                <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                <IngredientsWrapper>
                  {item.missedIngredients.map((ingredient, index) => {
                    return <p key={index}>{ingredient.name}</p>;
                  })}
                  {item.usedIngredients.map((ingredient, index) => {
                    return (
                      <b key={index}>
                        <p>{ingredient.name}</p>
                      </b>
                    );
                  })}
                </IngredientsWrapper>
              </TextWrapper>
            </MiniCard>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </Gallery>
  );
};
```

`RecipeDetails.js` Component:

```js
const DetailedRecipe = (props) => {
  
  //id property always returns empty
  console.log(props)
  const info = {
    apiURL: `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${props.id}/information`,
    apiKey: "***",
    apiURL2: `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${props.id}/analyzedInstructions`,
  };
  
  const {
    data: recipe,
    error: recipeError,
    isLoading: recipeIsLoading,
  } = useFetch(`${info.apiURL}?apiKey=${info.apiKey}`);

  

  

  return ();
};
```

Comment: Try setting the default value of `id` to a random string and see if it gets logged

Comment: @CopyrightC yes, it does: {id: "randomString", testing: "testing"}

Comment: that means there's problem in the testing part of your code

Comment: Can you explain it further? What I did in the App.js: const [id, setId] = useState("randomString")

Answer (score 0):

There should be some codes like following in StaffPicks.js

```
const [id, setId] = useState("0")
...
<Card setId={setId}/>
```

Isn't it?

Comment: Actually, I set up const [id, setId] = useState('') in App.js like you can see above, 
Speaking of StaffPicks.js: I set up <Card setId={props.setId}/>

Comment: What is the full source cods of StaffPicks.js?